# How can I detect if the browser supports the gesturestart event?

Tags: javascript, html, touch

How can I detect if the browser supports the gesturestart and other gesture events? These events are used for pinch to rotate and zoom.

They seem to be only available on iOS.

I wish to emulate them if they are not available natively.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can simply check if event exists, something like this:

```
document.documentElement.ontouchstart !== 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, catches more devices/browsers :-

```
try {
  document.createEvent("gesturestart");
  alert(true);
}
catch (e) {
  alert(false);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, createEvent() does not take the event name as a parameter. It takes an event category, such as "MouseEvents" or "TouchEvents". It is not clear what it should be for gestures. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `ongesturestart` in `window` as:

```
if ('ongesturestart' in window){

  // do something 
}
```

Comment: `window.ongesturestart` is undefined on Safari, even though gesture events are supported. Try `'GestureEvent' in window`

Answer (score 0):

Other methods mentioned here will fail on MacOS Safari.

In MacOS Safari, `'ongesturestart' in window` returns `false`, even though gesture events like `gesturestart` are supported.

You can check for gesture support by checking for `GestureEvent`:

```
'GestureEvent' in window
```